# Wpf Combo Selection

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with WPF Combo box.

I bind a List< Pair < String, String> > (Destinations) on my Combo like that :

My pair class is defined like that :

```
/// <summary>
/// This class represents a pair.
/// </summary>
public class Pair<T, U>
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the first value.
    /// </summary>
    public T First 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the second value.
    /// </summary>
    public U Second 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Pair()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor by initialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pFirst">The first value.</param>
    /// <param name="pSecond">The second value.</param>
    public Pair(T pFirst, U pSecond)
    {
        this.First = pFirst;
        this.Second = pSecond;
    }

    #endregion
};
```

I tried to display only the Second property of my pair as Display of my combo. I tried :

DisplayMemberPath={Binding Destinations.Second} but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMemberPath="Second"
```

That should work as each item will be a `Pair`.